# which one is fast?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

I tried these operations:

> `(7 xor 5)` *and* `(7 - 5)`

and I get same answers. I want to know which operation is fast? Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: Do you mean in hardware?

Comment: As written with constant operands, both operations can be computed by the compiler.  Even if they are computed at runtime (possibly with variables instead of constants), they are equally fast (one clock cycle, probably, for the actual arithmetic; there will also be time taken to load the variables into registers, etc to add).  The calculations are not the same, though; change the values of the operands and you will get different answers, so you need to choose the expression that represents that calculation you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

## Both.

You should write code that **clearly expresses the operation you're trying to perform**.

The compiler / JITter will take care of making it fast.